# MySQL dots in table names

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL database called copra4server, with a table called db_version.
I enter:

```
USE copra4server;
SELECT version FROM db_version;
```

And I get `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'copra4server.db_version' doesn't exist`

Why is it trying to get a table named *dbname.tablename* and what does this dot notation mean?

Comment: What is unclear about the error?  The table does not exist in the database that you are using.

Comment: The displayed format is `[database].[table]`. Which tables exist in your database named `copra4server`?

Comment: Does your `show tables` list `db_version`?

Comment: It turns out the table called db_version was corrupt.  I just deleted everything and started over, and it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear. Your table `db_version` is not present in the `copra4server` database.

When  you are saying `USE copra4server;` then it means that you want to use your `copra4server` database

And when you select from the table `db_version` the table is not present hence results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about "databases" versus "database servers".

MySQL is a database server.  You can connect to it and see *databases*.  Note the plural here.  One server, many databases.

One of the databases on your server is called `copra4server`.  When you say:

```
USE copra4server
```

You are saying "my current database is now `copra4server`".  So, any table you reference will be assumed to be in that database.  Your query:

```
SELECT version FROM db_version;
```

Is really -- under the hood -- saying

```
SELECT version FROM copra4server..db_version;
```

And, the table does not exist, causing the error message.

By the way, if you are looking for the *database* version, the proper syntax is:

```
SELECT version()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how MySQL refers to tables (db.table) so it is clear that it is talking about the table in that db.

Check your spelling if you're sure the table exists.